# Deciding between using an array attribute or a nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Possibly a fairly basic question, but bear with me.

I'm building a page which has a number of pieces of modular content, represented by a `ContentBlock` model. Each `ContentBlock` has at least one link, each of which has a couple of different attributes. My initial approach was to just add these links as an array to the model, as there didn't seem to be any real need to store them separately in the database, and they don't have any logic of their own. Now that I'm looking at building a form for creating/editing a `ContentBlock` though, it seems like it would be much easier to build if there was a separate, nested model for the links.

I'm strongly considering converting to using a model, but my gut feeling is that it's kind of "wrong" to store something like as relatively trivial as the links are in the DB. Given I am still getting used to working with Rails, is this feeling misplaced? Should I just create models for anything and everything? Or should I be looking for some sort of minimum criteria before I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely easier to create forms for nested models. Since your links have attributes, I'd suggest making a model. I tend to err on the side of making models for concepts that can't easily fit into fields. If you're worried about query performance, you can always do [eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).

Comment: In the end I have gone with nested models, just because it's the most straight forward and practical solution to the problem at hand, and there wasn't really a good reason not too. I think I just got caught up over-analysing things and looking for an "ideologically better" way rather than a more practical one.

Also, thanks for the tip about eager loading!

Answer (score 0):

I think depends on how much data you plan on managing, what you want to do against that data,  what that data represents, etc...

One project we had was to build something that allowed creation of recipes for a group of restaurants. Recipe (some text, like instructions, etc...) -> Ingredient, we went with an array, as these were all single lined text and there would never be more than several hand fulls. Also, the ingredients had no further dependencies. The Recipes would only be rendered out to html and there would be no searching against them (not against the db at least).

Another project required building a Page, very similar to yours, but each "component" of the page did different things and some where linked to other objects in the app, like Videos and other assets, templates, etc... We had seen people do this type of stuff entire through a wysiwyg or through some JS way and saved the entire payload/structure in the DB. We found both to be extremely messy.

And one concern that came up was what happened if an asset/associated object was mistakenly or purposely deleted but lived throughout many pages. Using models allowed to ensure that if something got removed, it got removed within all it's linked associations (though this posed problems of it's own, but more regarding the page making sense when displayed more than anything else).

Also, our Page had the potential of becoming extremely large with different types of components with different looks and inter-activities, that this really was the only way we could properly manage it.

So I would look at your requirements and plan accordingly, context matters. And if you have to change it (which happens, a lot) then you'll change it.